# Backbone-support nested view and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, backbone.js, chromium

It's the first time I use backbone-support to handle zombie views.
Before introducing it, I did not have the following problem:

```
    this.$el.append(this.template());

    // this view fills up a select with options taken from a web services
    this.renderChildInto(new App.view.ResourcesView({name: "idActivityDesc", url: "/wfc-services/resources/activities"}), "#divIdActivityDesc");

    // population of the forms elements according to the loaded model
    this.populateSelectElements();
    this.populateTextElements();

    if(this.model.get('completed')) {
        this.$("#active").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    this.delegateEvents(this.events);
    return this;
```

With Firefox it's all working fine. If the model is empty the `select` elements are going to be set up with default elements. In my case is **selectedIndex** to **-1**.

Going in debug inside the view everything seems fine. I have the problem when the view is going to be happened to the parent via the method `renderChildInto`. The dom is fine, but without the changes derived from the `populateSelectElements()` if the model is empty. If it's not empty I have no problem and the view is working fine.

I'm really puzzled about it because before the `return this;` statement, even in Chrome/Chromium I see the **selectedIndex** to **-1**. But in the final rendered view on the browser I see the select having **selectedIndex** to **0**.

In the composite_view.js the called code is:

```
  renderChild: function(view) {
    view.render();
    this.children.push(view);
    view.parent = this;
  },

  renderChildInto: function(view, container) {
    this.renderChild(view);
    this.$(container).html(view.el);
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the end of this story.

I found from many sources, including stackoverflow, that it is possible to use selectedIndex to -1.

I'm not a frontend developer and I do not have so much experience with browser compatibility so I found the help I needed from a colleague of mine that is expert in this thing and basically suggested me that this type of usage of selectedIndex was really weird.

He suggested me to use a default option element with value to "-" or whatever was compliant with the domain to define an empty element.

Worked like a charm and since we actually did a good job in the design we had just to change the selectedIndex from -1 to 0.